# How to reinstall all applications with desktop-files in simple way?

Tags: apt, software-installation, .desktop

I have Ubuntu system with a lot packages and applications installed.
Let's name this system as a *source*. The applications here were installed only as deb-packages.
I need to install application with desktop-files on new system (*target*).

How can I do this?

Comment: Nice Q&A, I've been wondering how to do that for a long time. However, you should be more specific about _which_ applications this procedure will reinstall. The correct answer to your question as it stands now is "it's impossible to automate this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At first** we need to get the list of executables on *source* system with command like:

`dpkg -S $(which $(grep -r ^Exec --no-filename /usr/share/applications/ | sed 's/Exec=//' | awk '{print $1}' ) | grep -v /home/$USER | grep -v /usr/local) 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/://' | sort -u > apps-list.txt`

(command is formatted as in-line code to provide readability, please do not change it to code block)

Command above parses all desktop-files in `/usr/share/applications/`, extracts contents of `Exec=` lines, skips applications installed in home folder and in `/usr/local`, then finds corresponding paths and finally transforms them to the list of packages to store in text file.

**At second** on *target* we can simply install these applications with command like

```
sudo apt install $(cat apps-list.txt)
```

Note: we can skip non-existent packages by filtering them out using grep:

`sudo apt install $(cat apps-list.txt | grep -v -E "app-not-found1|app-not-found2")`